# Passing arrays to methods

Tags: c#, arrays

Even though all variables are arrays I seem to be getting errors stating that conversion from string to string[] variables is not possible.

```
class Program
{

    private static int[] testKey = { 10, 12, 15, 18, 2, 1, 200 };
    private static string[] testVar1 = { "hello", "albert", "france", "john", "version", "zebra" };
    private static string[] testVar2 = { "helllllllo", "jordan", "land", "Hobart", "Hogwarts", "hamburger", "Code" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int currentLineCount = 0; currentLineCount < 233; currentLineCount++)
        {
            OrderAZ(testKey[currentLineCount], testVar1[currentLineCount], testVar2[currentLineCount]);
        }
        //Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'
        //Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'
        //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'int[]'
    }

    public static void OrderAZ(int[] sortKey, string[] sortVariableTwo, string[] sortVariableOne)
    {
       //sort method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testKey` is an array of `int`, but `testKey[currentLineCount]` is an `int`. The `OrderAZ` method expects a `int[]`, not an `int` (and similarly for the other parameters). You need to either pass an array, or change the signature of your `OrderAZ` method to accept an `int` (hard to tell without knowing what your code is supposed to do).

Comment: also same goes with testVar1 and testVar2.

Comment: @Valkyriee indeed.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help! I got it working now. I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple as changing from array to non array. Has been doing my head in for hours. 

 OrderAZ(testKey, testVar1, testVar2); did the trick then a seperate method for the output with that For Loop in the DisplayAZ method instead.

DisplayAZ(testKey, testVar1, testVar2);

I just made a sort method which is now working too as it uses the .toarray() parameter to ensure all are arrays.

Answer (score 1):

if you want send a string as an array you may need to use a string method to convert it in to a string array such a [string.split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)  , a string is not an array of strings as a int is not an array of int till you convert them in to it somehow.

In this case you are sending ítems of the array and an ítem of an array of strings is actually a string, so your method has to recieve a string, but if you want to send the whole array then remove the whole brackets part on the call, for example:

```
OrderAZ(testKey, testVar1, ...);
```

Then you can keep your method as it is. Good luck!